# What does this ($<) do in makefiles?

Tags: makefile

Hi what this command do?

```
 $<
```

I wasn't able to understand it by reading the GNUmakefile manual. Therefore I ask you for help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Documented in the section on [Automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$< represents the first dependency/prerequisite.

For example:

If you are trying to compile the file abc.cpp:

```
abc.o: abc.cpp abc.h
    g++ -c $< -o abc.o
```

$< represents abc.cpp

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables